# C : How to get row and colum of matrix given cell, row length and col length

Tags: c

Is it possible to get row and colum of matrix given cell, row length and col length ?

example :
matrix 10x10

cell : 4

should be:
[0,3]

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to make it answerable.  We would need to see some code.

Comment: What would the answer be if `cell = 19`? How about for `cell = 50`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming row major ordering

```
i = col
j = row
k = element number
l = width

i = k % width
j = floor( k / width )
```

Comment: Hi , width is number of columns ?

Comment: In the case of row major ordering, yes. It's pretty easy to understand if you think about how you'd calculate the index of an element given it's row and column position. (k = j*width + i). It then becomes a matter of simple arithmetic to reverse the process. Of course in the wild you'll also encounter column major ordering (most prominently in computer graphics), in which case you've to swap the roles of rows and columns.